# jQuery - get attribute returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alrighty, this is going to be really easy I'm sure, but after searching a fair amount and visiting the jQuery IRC, I still can't get this to work.  Here's what I have going on.

I need to get the `contentURL` value - in this case, `http://contenturl.com'`. (see XML below post)

According to other SO posts and IRC people, this should have worked. However, it returns 'undefined'.

```
var videoUrl = $('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').attr('content');
```

So I got rid of `.attr('content');` and set a break point and I can see that I get an object, and inside that object I can see that `content: "http://contenturl.com"` is there.

How the heck do I get that URL?

```
<div class="my_class">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="description, blah blah" />
    <meta itemprop="duration" content="00:02:10:00" />
    <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="http://thumbnailurl.com" />
    <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="http://contenturl.com"/>
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead. Although both would work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/sj1xhwuf/

Comment: [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x3kdf47/). @MelanciaUK `.attr` is correct in this case.

Comment: `meta` tags are only valid within the `head` element. I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve by putting them inside a `div` element.

Comment: Well wtf. Both `.prop()` and `.attr()` works...No idea what I did before. @MelanciaUK & @Blazemonger, both of your solutions work. What should I do regarding accepting an answer? Also, @JamesDonnelly, this isn't my website that I'm grabbing so I can't say why they're doing that.

Comment: If it's working now as it is, just close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The selector returns an array of matching elements. They can be accessed individually with the *array index getter syntax*.

e.g.:

```
jQuery('div')[0] 

-or- 

$('meta[itemprop=contentURL]')[0].content,
```

That will give you the first div in the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/75b59w6v/10/